# Ball motion in water

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, water, projectile

[image: the red line in the middle is velocity]I am analyzing a video of a ball falling in water with tracker.

The ball falls in a free fall for few seconds before it reaches a glass of water. The ball goes down till 3/4 of the glass, then stops and goes up again.

I am trying to understand acceleration and velocity graphs. 
In the first one, acceleration graphs steep positive a frame before the ball actually touches the water. Afterwards, acceleration just oscillates up and down. Why does it behave so? Why does it change before the ball touches the water? Is it just because the program can't track all the points?

Once the ball stops at 3/4 of the glass, velocity reaches a value, that remains constant while the ball is getting up. I do not get why it does not change getting up?

In the graph the middle red line is velocity, while the other is acceleration.

Hope it is clear my question

Comment: There's a lot of experimental error going into the acceleration. Check out the error in your velocity and how much it could affect an individual calculation of the acceleration at a point. It would be good to plot that error as well because without showing the error it's hard to judge whats going on

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I do not know why the description of the graph sis not appear. Anyway, the red line in the middle represent the velocity, while the other is acceleration. I overlapped the two graphs. At point 6 acceleration start to change, but the ball hasn't touch the water yet. Then why the versus of acceleration start to change before?